# boost multi_index_container changing keys -> incorret state of container

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, key, boost-multi-index

Supposed we have a multi index container:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/tag.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/key_extractors.hpp>

struct A{
A(int i){id=i;}
    int id;
};

typedef boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<
    A * ,
    boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
        boost::multi_index::random_access<
            boost::multi_index::tag<by_insertion>
        >, // this index represents insertion order
        boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<
            boost::multi_index::tag<by_id>,
            boost::multi_index::member<A, int, &A::id>
        >
    >
> MapType;

MapType map;

map.get<1>().insert(new A(1));
map.get<1>().insert(new A(2));

(*map.get<1>().find(1))->id=4; // HERE IF I CHANGE THE KEY, I CAN NOT FIND either key=4 or 1

MapType::nth_index<1>::type::iterator it = map.get<1>().find(4);
if(it != map.get<1>().end() ){
    std::cout << "FOUND A:" << *it << std::endl;
} // DOES NOT WORK?? WHY CANT I FIND the ELement with Key 4?
```

The problem is now that i probably set up the `boost::multi_index::member<A, int, &A::a>` wrongly because when I change some key. I cannot find the element with key = 4?

Whats wrongly used here?
Any help really appreciated!

Comment: Wait: are you are changing the value you look things up on in the map, and expecting the map to magically know about this?  Generally, changing "the thing being looked up on" in a container without informing the container results in UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, hashed indices do not store hash values, they always calculate it on the fly. Why do you want to change keys yet keep looking up by the old values?

Comment: So why can i not find the element with key = 4  `MapType::nth_index<1>::type::iterator it = map.get<1>().find(4);
if(it != map.get<1>().end() ){
    std::cout << "FOUND A:" << *it << std::endl;
}`

this will not work!

Comment: Because the element is stored as if key = 1. What's happening is:
* If you look for 4, you end up in an empty bucket.
* If you look for 1, you spot the element but when checking the key this is 4, so lookup fails as well.

Comment: And, repeating my question: why do you want to do this?

Comment: Thanks for this awesome explanation!. I dont want to change the key, but the underlying problem is that if I put pointers in the container only then I am able to change the elements (container has only read access, making all deferenced iterators of type A* const where it is possible to change the underlying instance of A ) but then I am able to change the key I have based my container on,as long as this key is not constant in the class A. Is this not stupid?

Answer (score 1):

Answering Gabriel's last comment: using a container of pointers just to have write access to the elements is overkill. You can do instead one of the following:

- Use `modify()`, which checks if the modified element has to be relocated as a consequence of some key having been touched.
- If you know you won't change a key, cast with `const_cast<A&>()` and modify as you please.

In general, Boost.MultiIndex has no way to grant write access only to non-key parts of the element.

Comment: Jeah, sorry for my missleading describtion: I would like to have pointers in this container, I am not doing this to be able to change the objects. It is a bit subtle but in my test above, I occasionally circumvented the fact that the container should only grant const access which it does, but has no affect for a pointer. so there was my problem. My key needs to be anyway constant `const A::id` in the class, so a pointer to `A` is ok.

Using modify() is one option but is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: Another one would be to gather the pointer to `A` and the `key` in a new  class `Data`